# Create content type with fields that are content types

Tags: entities, nodes

I am trying to do something similar to [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26428/create-content-types-containing-other-content-types)

I have a catalog content type.  I want to be able to add one or more books related to the catalog topic to this content type. These books would be of a custom content type. Each book would only be tied to a single catalog but a catalog may have many books.

I want to create a page for each catalog topic that has the fields of the catalog content type (like description etc) and then a list of all the books related to the catalog topic.

I want authenticated users to be able to add new books ("add book" link) to the catalog and also to be able to create new catalogs for the topics they choose. When a new catalog is created, it should have an "add book" link.

How would do this?

Comment: If you wan't to connect certain nodes you could use the http://drupal.org/project/entityreference or http://drupal.org/project/references module, you should also look on the http://drupal.org/project/field_collection module which will make it possible to connect an unlimited number of nodes

Answer (score 0):

A think you could be interested in [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection)